# Bypass certificate on IIS hosted Blazor Server SignalR app

Tags: authentication, iis, ssl-certificate, signalr, blazor-server-side

I have an Blazor .net core app hosted on IIS on Windows Server 2019. I am using certificate authentication using smart card to log in to the app and the app works fine with Anonymous Authentication enabled with every other authentication method disabled on the Authentication setting in the IIS.

My Program.cs is shown below:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
string connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connString));
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });
builder.Services.AddSignalRCore();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICertificateValidationService, CertificateValidationService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserManagement, UserManagement>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
        CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                    .GetRequiredService<ICertificateValidationService>();

                if (validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
                {
                    var claims = new[]
                    {
                        new Claim(
                            ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                            context.ClientCertificate.Subject,
                            ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                        new Claim(
                            ClaimTypes.Name,
                            context.ClientCertificate.Subject,
                            ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                    };

                    context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                        new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                    context.Success();
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<EditingNotificationHub>("/editingHub");
});
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

The app manages to log in using my smart card and app works fine where SignalR hub connection is not established. When I load a page that tries to initialize a signalR hub connection, the application crashes. As I went to see the event viewer on the IIS, it shows 403 error.

The code in the razor file (HomeComponent.razor) where I am initializing the hubconnection is given below, where I tried bypassing the certificate check (I also tried without including the HttpMessageHandlerFactory options):

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(_navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/editingHub"), options => {
            options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (msg) =>
            {
                if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                {
                    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                    return message;
                }

                return message;
            };
        }).WithAutomaticReconnect().Build();

        hubConnection.On<int, bool, int>("ReceiveMessage", (senderID, editingStatus, prid) =>
        {
            notification = new EditingNotification() { UserID = senderID, Editing = editingStatus, PRID = prid };
            if(prid == PRNum)
            {
                if (editingStatus)
                {
                    userEditing = editingStatus;
                    userEditingMessage = "is editing.";
                }
                else
                {
                    userEditingMessage = "has finished editing, please reload the page.";
                }
            }
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
```

In the event viewer I get the following:

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost
EventId: 111
SpanId: 083e8e84ca56fc4b
TraceId: dfa84b4238d669b811b5aca6e1cc31c7
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 80002230-0001-c600-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /_blazor
TransportConnectionId: z1Bby_rgcRzSoz45wN1wIg

Unhandled exception in circuit 'NCCj9qdxaYD99Y9ZlZswPHWLazRLu_r5xk_4BA_RBP0'.

Exception: 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WORKS.Pages.PurchaseRequestDetailsView.PurchaseRequestDetailsView.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Users\613163\Desktop\WORKS\WORKS\Pages\PurchaseRequestDetailsView\PurchaseRequestDetailsView.razor:line 320
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

I also have WebSocket Protocol installed in the IIS.

The app along with signalR hub connection does work on IIS Express on Visual Studio 2022. It only crashes on the hosted IIS.

I hoped that installing WebSocket Protocol in the IIS and modifying the code in the HomeComponent.razor file:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(_navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/editingHub"), options => {
            options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
            options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (msg) =>
            {
                if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                {
                    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                    return message;
                }

                return message;
            };
            options.WebSocketConfiguration = wsc => wsc.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => true;
        }).WithAutomaticReconnect().Build();

        hubConnection.On<int, bool, int>("ReceiveMessage", (senderID, editingStatus, prid) =>
        {
            notification = new EditingNotification() { UserID = senderID, Editing = editingStatus, PRID = prid };
            if(prid == PRNum)
            {
                if (editingStatus)
                {
                    userEditing = editingStatus;
                    userEditingMessage = "is editing.";
                }
                else
                {
                    userEditingMessage = "has finished editing, please reload the page.";
                }
            }
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
```

The resulting code didnt work. I also tried removing options.UseDefaultCredentials = true and the problem persisted.

I am kinda clueless right now and trying to figure out whether I have missed anything.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.